# Client side authentication with express

Tags: javascript, express, authentication

I made a simple game with plain javascript and html. I have set up a proxy server because I use openai's chatgpt api so I don't get it exposed. I make the call by pressing a button but I don't want people to send any number of requests to the site manually so they can't spend all the money I allowed for the day. I only want to allow to send calls from my javascript code when the button is pressed.
Additionally I want to set up an sql server to save their score and I don't want them saving manually only at the end of the game when they lost.
I don't want players to have to log in only to provide a username by which their score will be saved like an arcade machine but I don't think logging in would solve it.

I looked up sessions and jwt and I think it would solve that users can't send fake information but I don't see it can solve that they can send any number of calls because as I see it they can send any number of calls with the same token manually.
I thought about having an id for every call and make it so the same call can't be made twice. Would that solve it combined with the jwt tokens?

```
// Routes
app.use('/api', cookieJwtAuth, require('./routes/openai'))
```

This is how I make the call to my proxy server. But if someone just puts this url into his browser it sends the call again even with the jwt tokens. Or am I misunderstanding something?

```
const url = `/api?desc=${description}`
const res = await fetch(url)
```